# Is there a way to vectorise this dynamic time warping algorithm?

Tags: python, algorithm, optimization, vectorization, distance

The dynamic time warping algorithm provides a notion of distance between two temporal sequences which may vary in speed. If I have N sequences to compare to each other, I can construct a NXN symmetric matrix with a nule diagonal by applying the algorithm pairwise. However, this is very slow for long two-dimensional sequences. Therefore, I am trying to vectorise the code to speed up this matrix computation. Importantly, I also want to extract the indices defining the optimal alignment.

My code for pairwise comparison so far :

```
import math
import numpy as np

seq1 = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 2)) #Two dim sequences
seq2 = np.random.randint(100, size=(100, 2))

def seqdist(seq1, seq2):                      # dynamic time warping function

    ns = len(seq1)
    nt = len(seq2)

    D = np.zeros((ns+1, nt+1))+math.inf
    D[0, 0] = 0
    cost = np.zeros((ns,nt))

    for i in range(ns):
       for j in range(nt): 

          cost[i,j] = np.linalg.norm(seq1[i,:]-seq2[j,:])
          D[i+1, j+1] = cost[i,j]+min([D[i, j+1], D[i+1, j], D[i, j]])

    d = D[ns,nt]                            # distance

    matchidx = [[ns-1, nt-1]]              # backwards optimal alignment computation 
    i = ns
    j = nt
    for k in range(ns+nt+2):
        idx = np.argmin([D[i-1, j], D[i, j-1], D[i-1, j-1]])
        if idx == 0 and i > 1 and j > 0:
           matchidx.append([i-2, j-1])
           i -= 1
        elif idx == 1 and i > 0 and j > 1:
             matchidx.append([i-1, j-2])
             j -= 1
        elif idx == 2 and i > 1 and j > 1:
             matchidx.append([i-2, j-2])
             i -= 1
             j -= 1
        else:
             break

    matchidx.reverse()

    return d, matchidx

[d,matchidx] = seqdist(seq1,seq2) #try it
```

Comment: It is hard to make useful comments on the question as stated. You can have a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for general guidelines. You probably want to make sure that you can copy-paste the code and run it, which is not the case now (due to indentation issues).

Comment: Other than that, I get `d` equal to infinity in this example. If your code is correct and you want better performance, you may want to include sample sequences that result in a finite distance with respect to the "dynamic time warping algorithm" as you describe it.

Comment: There were some indents wrong, I fixed them. The distance is finite.

Comment: Looks good to me, not sure why I was seeing infinite distance in my output yesterday.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one re-write of your code that makes it more amenable to `numba.jit`. This is not exactly a vectorized solution, but I see a speedup by a factor of 230 for this benchmark.

```
from numba import jit
from scipy import spatial

@jit
def D_from_cost(cost, D):
  # operates on D inplace
  ns, nt = cost.shape
  for i in range(ns):
    for j in range(nt):
      D[i+1, j+1] = cost[i,j]+min(D[i, j+1], D[i+1, j], D[i, j])
      # avoiding the list creation inside mean enables better jit performance
      # D[i+1, j+1] = cost[i,j]+min([D[i, j+1], D[i+1, j], D[i, j]])

@jit
def get_d(D, matchidx):
  ns = D.shape[0] - 1
  nt = D.shape[1] - 1
  d = D[ns,nt]

  matchidx[0,0] = ns - 1
  matchidx[0,1] = nt - 1
  i = ns
  j = nt
  for k in range(1, ns+nt+3):
    idx = 0
    if not (D[i-1,j] <= D[i,j-1] and D[i-1,j] <= D[i-1,j-1]):
      if D[i,j-1] <= D[i-1,j-1]:
        idx = 1
      else:
        idx = 2

    if idx == 0 and i > 1 and j > 0:
      # matchidx.append([i-2, j-1])
      matchidx[k,0] = i - 2
      matchidx[k,1] = j - 1
      i -= 1
    elif idx == 1 and i > 0 and j > 1:
      # matchidx.append([i-1, j-2])
      matchidx[k,0] = i-1
      matchidx[k,1] = j-2
      j -= 1
    elif idx == 2 and i > 1 and j > 1:
      # matchidx.append([i-2, j-2])
      matchidx[k,0] = i-2
      matchidx[k,1] = j-2
      i -= 1
      j -= 1
    else:
      break

  return d, matchidx[:k]


def seqdist2(seq1, seq2):
  ns = len(seq1)
  nt = len(seq2)

  cost = spatial.distance_matrix(seq1, seq2)

  # initialize and update D
  D = np.full((ns+1, nt+1), np.inf)
  D[0, 0] = 0
  D_from_cost(cost, D)

  matchidx = np.zeros((ns+nt+2,2), dtype=np.int)
  d, matchidx = get_d(D, matchidx)
  return d, matchidx[::-1].tolist()

assert seqdist2(seq1, seq2) == seqdist(seq1, seq2)

%timeit seqdist2(seq1, seq2) # 1000 loops, best of 3: 365 µs per loop
%timeit seqdist(seq1, seq2)  # 10 loops, best of 3: 86.1 ms per loop
```

Here are some changes:

1. `cost` is calculated using `spatial.distance_matrix`.
2. The definition of `idx` is replaced with a bunch of ugly if statements that makes the compiled code faster.
3. `min([D[i, j+1], D[i+1, j], D[i, j]])` is replaced with `min(D[i, j+1], D[i+1, j], D[i, j])`, i.e. instead of taking min of a list, we take min of three values. This leads to a surprising speedup under `jit`.
4. `matchidx` is preallocated as a numpy array and truncated to the right size just before output.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it is indeed faster for long sequences. However, I noticed that a weird thing happens for the case of different length sequences, the kernel gets restarted. For example : size=(100, 2) and size=(50, 2). This is not the case for the original function.

Comment: Ok, it just needed a change: nt = D.shape[0] - 1 to nt = D.shape[1] - 1

Comment: Oh well, indexing is hard. Good catch. Let me know if the updated code works for your benchmarks.